# Calculating the average of integer inputs in an array

Tags: java, arrays, math, average

I need to calculate a random input of integers in an array. Everything works fine but I get for every Input a new calculation of all values inside the array.

Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    while (sc.hasNextInt()) { // this loop breaks there is no more int input.
        numbers.add(sc.nextInt());

        int l = numbers.size();

        double total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {

            total = total + numbers.get(i);

            double average = total / numbers.size();
            System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
        }
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, move the calculation out of the loop.

Comment: Servus!  It's not very clear what you're actually asking.  Can you give some sample input, and state what output you're expecting versus what output you actually get?  Also, can you clarify if this is a homework assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was pointed out, you should calculate the average of your numbers only *after* the sum of all the numbers is found.

Your program needs to be cut into separate steps that should happen one after the other instead of all at once:

1. Retrieve input from the user, adding each integer to the list
2. Loop through all integers in the list, adding to `total`
3. Calculate the average
4. Display results

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    while (sc.hasNextInt())
        numbers.add(sc.nextInt());
    sc.close(); // Remember to close the input stream when finished

    double total = 0;
    for (int num : numbers) // Loop through all ints in the list
        total += num; // Add each int to total

    double average = total / numbers.size();
    System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
    System.out.println(numbers);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) { // this loop breaks there is no more int input.
            numbers.add(sc.nextInt());

            int l = numbers.size();

            double total = 0;


        }

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {

                total = total + numbers.get(i);

                double average = total / numbers.size();
                System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
            }

            System.out.println(numbers);

}
```

Comment: If you are going to answer questions, avoid giving answers that are mainly code dumps as they are not that helpful to future visitors. Instead strive to explain the reasons behind the problems that the original poster is having as well as how to solve those problems. This way your answer will be helpful to future visitors with similar problems and not just the original poster.